# impossible constraint in asm - unspecific GCC message

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

I'm learning GCC extended asm options

```
asm goto (
    "clc\n"
    "lo:\t"
    "lods\t%[ax]\n\t"
    "lea\t%[wc](%[base], %[off], %[k]), %[la]"
    "adc\t%[ax], (%[la])\n\t"
    "inc\t%[off]\n\t"
    "jnz\tlo\n\t"
    "jnc\t%l[nocarry]\n"
    : 
    : [base] "d" (th), [oz] "S" (oz), [wc] "I" (wc*sizeof(uInt)),
      [k] "N" (sizeof(uInt)), [la] "b" (0), [ax] "a" (0), [off] "c" (-wc)
    : 
    : nocarry
);
```

And having in compilation:

```
>  impossible constraint in 'asm'
```

Have tried to comment all constraints one-by-one, same result.
Please, help!

gcc version 4.6.1 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3), i686-linux-gnu (32bit),
kernel 3.0.0-14-generic

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your statement is partial and lacks the definitions of the variables used to populate the input constraints of your assembly instruction.

The most likely candidate is the `[wc] "I" (wc * sizeof(uInt))` expression if `wc` is anything else but a compile-time constant - `"I"` constraints must be evaluatable to an immediate. Could also be the `[k] "N" (sizeof(uInt))` because that's not a match for `lea`.

I'd suggest changing the statement to:

```
asm (
    "lea    (%[base], %[off], %[k]), %[base]\n\t"
    "neg    %[off]\n\t"
    "clc\n\t"
    "lo:    "
    "lods   %[ax]\n\t"
    "lea    (%[base], %[off], %[k]), %[la]\n\t"
    "adc    %[ax], (%[la])\n\t"
    "inc    %[off]\n\t"
    "jnz    lo\n\t"
    "jnc    %l[nocarry]\n"
: 
: [k] "I"(sizeof(uInt)), [base] "d" (th), [oz] "S" (oz),
  [la] "b" (0), [ax] "a" (0), [off] "c" (wc)
: 
: nocarry
);
```

but you might want to evaluate letting the compiler more freedom to choose (like, saying `[base] "r" (th + wc)` assuming `th` is `uInt*`). Likewise, with the assembly instructions you have, there's no explicit need to use `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"` or `"d"`, so you artificially limit which regs the compiler may choose. If that's what you want, maybe writing the function fully in assembly is better / easier than trying to coerce the compiler.

Comment: Thank you for useful advice. `wc` is the "length" member of arbitrary precision ariphmetic class, of cause nonstatic.

But actually i decided to change the approach, this is current (working :) variant:

Answer (score 0):

```
BigInt & BigInt::operator+=(const BigInt &rhs)
{
    this->grow(rhs.wc);
    uInt *th = (uInt*)words, *oz = (uInt*)rhs.words;
    asm goto (
        "clc\n"
        "l1:\t"
        "mov\t(%[oz]), %[ax]\n\t"
        "adc\t%[ax], (%[th])\n\t"
        "lahf\n\t"
        "add\t%[ws], %[th]\n\t"
        "add\t%[ws], %[oz]\n\t"
        "sahf\n\t"
        "loop\tl1\n\t"
        "jnc\t%l[nocarry]\n"
        : 
        : [th] "r" (th), [oz] "r" (oz),
          [ws] "I" (sizeof(uInt)), [ax] "a" ((uInt)0), "c" (wc)
        : 
        : nocarry
    );
```